# Active vs passive transformation in parity violation

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, coordinate-systems, parity, foundations

I am no familiar with electroweak force so I will pose this scenario.
Suppose  we have a positive charge   at rest  and an electric field  pointing  to the  right  than the particle would accelerate to right. Now suppose that we inverted the electric field , that is the electric field is pointing to the left , if  the acceleration would still point to the right that would be a parity violation.

Let us suppose that this scenario is true . The experience above what we call active transformation.
Now suppose we change to from a right hand coordinate system to a left handed coordinate system , in this case the electric field and the acceleration would point in the same direction.

Is this not a contradiction in the statement that passive  and active transformation are equivalent?

Comment: "The experience above [is] what we call active transformation" Either I am misunderstanding you are this is incorrect. Acceleration and the electric field are both vectors. Under any active or passive transformation, they transform in exactly the same way, such that they are still pointing in the same direction afterwards. You cannot transform parts of your coordinate system and call it an active transformation

Comment: @cream this was hypothetical. Suppose that electric field had such propertie that i mentioned

Comment: Then, I do not understand the question. If you assume that the "active transformation" different from the usual one, it is indeed not equivalent to the passive transformation.

Comment: @cream electroweak force has such propertie

Comment: That is true but I do not see the connection to electroweak forces. Could you clarify in your question: How does the system look in the beginning? What transformation are you performing on it? How does the system look afterwards? Why do you think this is an active transformation in the usual sense?